# Inverse every n rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reverse

How would I go about reversing every n rows in a dataframe. I have a dataframe where the rows start with H24 and end with H1 for every day. Now I would like to reverse every 24 rows so the day starts with H1 and ends with H24 (for all the days in the dataframe). Do i need to loop over the dataframe or is there a more efficient solution?

The dataframe looks like this:
[df5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6zH3.png)

and this is the code i used so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.read_csv('Podatki_vsi_NOVE.csv',sep=';')
df1 = pd.read_csv('Podatki_vsi_OVE.csv')
df5 = df1.reindex(index=df1.index[::-1])
```

The problem is that one set of data (df0) starts at an earlier date for example (1.1.2016) and continues to the last date (1.1.2018) but the second set of data start at the last date (1.1.2018) and ends with earlier date (1.1.2016). Now, as it can be seen, from the code, I have already inversed the entire dataframe df1 and the result is df5. the problem of df5 (as seen from the picture) is that every day, now that it is inversed, starts with H24 not with H1 as it should.

Output:
[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S2i9.png)
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5NmE.png)

Comment: Could you provide an example input and output representative of your data to clarify what you're after? Solutions can vary depending on what your actual case is... (are all the rows consecutive for the same 24 hour period or is there a datetime that can identify days/be used to identify periods etc...)

Comment: Sorry for me being unclear, I have edited the post, hope it clarifies what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
df5["hour"] = df5["Unnamed: 0"].apply(lambda x: int(x[1:]))    
df5 = df5.sort_values(["datum", "hour"])
```

Comment: @JonClements Yes you are right. I am modifying my answer

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I ve been looking through the data and it seems it sorted the data like this:
1.1.2016 (for 24 hours, starting at H1 and ending with H24 as it should)
1.1.2017
1.1.2018
2.1.2016
2.1.2017
2.1.2018
...
What I wouldn need is to go chronologicaly from 1.1.2016 day by day to todays date. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: This is the code so far:
`import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.read_csv('Podatki_vsi_NOVE.csv',sep=';')
df1 = pd.read_csv('Podatki_vsi_OVE.csv')
df5 = df1.reindex(index=df1.index[::-1])
df5["hour"] = df5["Unnamed: 0"].apply(lambda x: int(x[1:]))    
df5 = df5.sort_values(["datum", "hour"])
df6 = df5.reset_index(drop=True)

df7 = pd.concat([df0, df6], axis=1)`

Comment: So it seems that it sorts by year/month/date instead of date/month/year. Can I reverse it?

Comment: For me it seems to work fine. Can you please share a sample output?

Comment: Hi, I updated the original post with pictures (output1 and output2) so you can see in what order I get the output. It seems to me that the sorting works in order of year/month/day. The dates in the output are dd/mm/yy.

Comment: I think you need to convert the 'datum' field into pandas datetime format first